# $\frac{d}{dt}X=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-2\\ 3&4\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}t\\ e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$ - can someone calculate this for me?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $$X'=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-2\\ 3&4\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}t\\ e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$

Please, I literally spent the last 3 hours calculating it but always is wrong, i tried various techniques but nope

Comment: If you have attempts, you should reproduce them here. That way, it is less work for us, and we can point out any errors.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709823/fracddtx-beginpmatrix-1-2-34-endpmatrixx-beginpmatrixt-e-t here's my attempt, I created this new let's say it "more neutral" thread because no one has answered me to my old one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\frac{d}{dt}X=\begin{pmatrix}-1&amp;-2\\ 3&amp;4\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}t\\ e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$ - can someone check what I'm doing wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709823/fracddtx-beginpmatrix-1-2-34-endpmatrixx-beginpmatrixt-e-t)

Answer (score 1):

$$X'=\begin{pmatrix}-1&-2\\ 3&4\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}t\\ e^{-t}\end{pmatrix}$$
**Hint:**
You can deduce that
$$(x+y)'=2(x+y)+t+e^{-t}$$
$$u'=2u+t+e^{-t}$$
Where $X= \pmatrix{x\\ y}$ and $u=x+y$. This can easily be solved.

Comment: How? Please tell me (also how you came to (+)′=2(+)++^(-t)), I've been looking up various techniques to solve this for the past 3 hours, and it always involved something like calculating the eigenvalue, invert matrix, some "Phi" matrix, etc. But it always seems to be extremely exhausting to calculate this because of the integrals which you get. 

And if I got (+)′=2(+)++^(−), what should I do with it next?

Comment: It's a first order linear  DE with $u=x+y$ @Student

Comment: But if I got u, how should I know what x and y would be equal to?

Comment: you find $x$  as a function of $y$ and t ...You substitute that in the second equation $y'=3x+4y+e^{-t}$  and solve this one and you are done. @Student

Comment: I don't understand, I've got $u=-\frac{1}{3e^t}-\frac{2t+1}{4}+c_1e^{2t}$, so what's next? Instead of y' i'll take u' - x' (and instead of y i'll take u - x) and I will be able to calculate x? And what's next? Should I repeat this for y? Or is there a "shortcut"?

Comment: Yes thats exactly that @Student substitute in the second equation $y=u-x$ and solve

Comment: Is it really faster than other techniques? It's just that you have to calculate 3 differential equations, it may be foolproof and the easiest to understand, but is it really the quickest? What about using this "Phi" matrix? Or this technique which involves this e^At function?

Comment: You just solved two differential equations. Not three. You can use eigenvalues and eigenvectors method  too. @Student

Comment: What about $\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ -5&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-cos\left(t\right)\\ sin\left(t\right)+cos\left(t\right)\end{pmatrix}$? Here, I cannot do any kind of subsitution, as I get (x+y)'=-4x-2y+sin(t)

Comment: The trick I used here dosen't work all the time. And it dosen't unfortunately works for the system you posted. @Student

Comment: So what should I do with this system?

Comment: where is the link to the post @Student

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712489/x-beginpmatrix11-5-3-endpmatrixx-beginpmatrix-cos-leftt-right

Comment: The trick will not work for that example @Student