# $X'=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ -5&-3\end{pmatrix}X+\begin{pmatrix}-\cos\left(t\right)\\ \sin\left(t\right)+\cos\left(t\right)\end{pmatrix}$ - What to do?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ -5&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-\cos\left(t\right)\\ \sin\left(t\right)+\cos\left(t\right)\end{pmatrix}   ;   \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\left(0\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -2\end{pmatrix}$

If using the Matrix Exponential I get complex functions as the result (and in general ridiculously long integrals like $\int \:\left(-\:\cos\left(t\right)\left(e^{\left(1-i\right)t}\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)+e^{\left(1+i\right)t}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\right)\right)+\left(\sin\left(t\right)+\cos\left(t\right)\right)\left(e^{\left(1-i\right)t}\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)+e^{\left(1+i\right)t}\left(-\frac{i}{2}\right)\right)\right)dt$

Is there a simpler way to calculate that?

Comment: You could get rid of the complex numbers by using the identity $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$

Answer (score 1):

This system can be solved without using Jordan normal form and matrix exponential. Let's make the change of variables
$$
y_1=x_1\qquad y_2=x_1+x_2-\cos t
$$
$$
x_1=y_1\qquad x_2=y_2-y_1+\cos t
$$
In these variables, the system is
$$
\dot y_1= \dot x_1= x_1+x_2-\cos t=y_2
$$
$$
\dot y_2=\dot x_1+\dot x_2+\sin t=x_1+x_2-\cos t
-5x_1-3x_2+\sin t+\cos t+\sin t
$$
$$
=-4x_1-2x_2+2\sin t=-2y_1-2y_2+2\sin t-2\cos t.
$$
This can be written as a second order linear ODE
$$
\ddot z+2\dot z+2z=2\sin t-2\cos t,
$$
where $z=y_1,\; \dot z= y_2$. Solving this equation, we obtain
$$
y_1=z=C_1 e^{-t}\cos t+ C_2 e^{-t}\sin t - \frac25 \sin t - \frac 65 \cos t. 
$$
Differentiation gives us
$$
y_2=\dot z= - C_1 e^{-t} \left( \cos t +\sin t \right)+C_2 e^{-t}\left( \cos t-\sin t
\right)+\frac65 \sin t - \frac 25 \cos t
$$
Finally,
$$
x_1=y_1=C_1 e^{-t}\cos t+ C_2 e^{-t}\sin t - \frac25 \sin t - \frac 65 \cos t
$$
$$
x_2=y_2-y_1+\cos t=  - C_1 e^{-t} \left( 2\cos t +\sin t \right)+C_2 e^{-t}\left( \cos t-2\sin t
\right)+\frac85 \sin t + \frac 95 \cos t.
$$
From the initial conditions $C_1=\frac{11}5$, $C_2=\frac35$.